# GCM Equivalent for Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a service that enables developers to send data from servers to both Android applications or Chrome apps and extensions.

I am developing a chrome and a firefox extension/add-on. I am using the Web Extension APIs for Firefox extension.

Now, Web Extension APIs don't support chrome.gcm.* APIs yet. Essentially, a firefox extension cannot talk to GCM.

Is there something else like GCM to which a firefox extension can talk to? Something provided by the Firefox just like GCM provided by Google for its browser Chrome? If not, can someone please explain how to achieve this in a Firefox Extension?

**Update**:
 Even for web apps, firefox doesn't use something similar to GCM. They use service workers. Can Firefox Browser Extensions interact with service workers?

Comment: Have you got an answer for that?

Comment: use websockets?

Answer (score 12):

Firefox extensions currently can’t use service workers directly ([according to an implementor who worked on service-workers support in Firefox](http://logs.glob.uno/?c=freenode%23whatwg&s=1%20Feb%202016&e=1%20Feb%202016#c983254)).

> Is there something else like GCM to which a firefox extension can talk to? Something provided by the Firefox just like GCM provided by Google for its browser Chrome?

Yes, there’s a Firefox equivalent of GCM. Firefox users receive push notifications from a server given by the `dom.push.serverURL` user preference. If you check `dom.push.serverURL` in `about:config`, you’ll see `wss://push.services.mozilla.com/`, which is the [**Mozilla Push Service**](https://mozilla-push-service.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)—essentially, Mozilla’s equivalent of GCM.

That runs an [**AutoPush**](https://autopush.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (Python-based open-source Push Server software project) backend, and the client part is (as the question notes) exposed to frontend code by a service worker.

So while there may be an alternative way Firefox extensions can connect with Mozilla Push Service, the only publicly-documented way is through the [standard Web Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API) that relies on service workers, which are not available yet for use in Firefox extensions.

Comment: So, do you know of any alternatives using which Firefox extensions can connect with Mozilla Push Service?

Comment: You might be able to use one of the Firefox modules that implement Web Push (http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/push/).

Comment: @Marco How? I think this also is for web apps only.

Comment: @ankitG those modules are internal, they can't be used by web content, but can be used by addons.
I'm not sure about the "how", you have to investigate by looking at their source code.

Comment: There's also something else that you could do. Create a web page that uses service workers and the standard Push API and somehow communicate data between the addon and the web page.