# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) not working with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have this Service Worker that receives notification well with Chrome,
but it's not receiving with firefox.

the Push listener is not fired at all in firefox (by debugging it),

PS: the service worker is  successfully registered, but it's not receiving notification.

what's the problem with my code?

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
console.log('Activated', event);
});

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(
    fetch('/path', {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'post',
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
            .then(function (data) {
                return self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
                    body: data.body,
                    icon: '/images/image.png',
                });
            });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('wrong', error);
    })
);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API#Push_workflow_summary), if you are using the [Channel Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API) to comunicate with the service worker, set up a new message channel ([`MessageChannel.MessageChannel()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel/MessageChannel)) and send port2 over to the service worker by calling [`Worker.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) on the service worker, in order to open up the communication channel. You should also set up a listener to respond to messages sent back from the service worker.

Make sure that you followed these [steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API#Setting_up_Google_Cloud_Messaging) on how to set up the GCM properly. You can also check this related link: [GCM Equivalent for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125710/gcm-equivalent-for-firefox)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for answering, but I am using the google gcm documentation for making the notification and I want to integrate it with Firefox. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You will need to share your code in the client for registering for push notifications.

With that said, once you register for push notifications, you will receive a subscription with an endpoint. In Firefox that endpoint will never be a GCM url, but a push server provided by Mozilla:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then((reg) => reg.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true }))
      .then((subscription) => {
          const endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
          // endpoint will have different server values when using this code in Chrome or Firefox.
```

Here are key notes to be considered:

- Are you registering for push notifications correctly in firefox?
- Check the url for the endpoint you will need to reach for performing the push notification, is a mozilla server one?
- Setup breakpoints just after the push listener to verify that you receive the push.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I successfully got the end point from Mozilla server, but I am not able to receive any notification from mozilla server. should I make a different push listener for mozilla server

Comment: these are the steps which I have followed,  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en

Comment: so I have checked your advises, only the last one not working , the push listener not triggered on Firefox, but works properly on google.

Comment: Are you sending a payload? For good examples of SW + push notifications you can check https://serviceworke.rs/