# Best way to implement GCM in a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, google-cloud-messaging

I've developed a Chrome extension that uses GCM to receive push messages. I would now like to port this extension to Firefox, but this has proven to be problematic since Firefox apparently does not support GCM.

I've found many different alternatives, but none of them seems to be optimal. I would like to know what is the best way to implement GCM in Firefox? If possible, I'd like to keep sending my messages through GCM, so I don't have to modify my sending script.

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, Firefox does not support GCM yet. However, you can use [Mozilla Push Service](https://mozilla-push-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as an equivalent of GCM. Here is a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125710/gcm-equivalent-for-firefox).

> All Web apps a Firefox user accesses that receive push notifications get them from a server given by the `dom.push.serverURL` user preference. If you check `dom.push.serverURL` in `about:config`, you’ll see `wss://push.services.mozilla.com/`.