# How does browser message server identify the particular browser to send message for push notification

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I understand chrome uses GCM message server to send messages that are sent from server. But how does it identify which browser to send.

Does browser sync with the message server when it gets a active internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

From this [thread](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web#can_i_prevent_duplicate_notifications_if_my_web_presence_has_multiple_origins_or_if_i_have_both_a_web_and_native_presence), it is stated here that there is some kind of ID for a users device and then on the server side match up the native app and web app subscription ID's and decide which one to send a push message.

For more information, check the these threads that can hep you to determine how the push message work on both Chrome and Mozilla.

- [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web)
- [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)
- [GCM Equivalent for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125710/gcm-equivalent-for-firefox/35133879)

Comment: How does it know whether a particular id has network connection at a particular time