# How to implement firefox Web-extensions Push notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Forgive me if you think its an obvious one, but *I didn't find any relevant(non-obsolete) material on the same*.

So, I have a chrome extension out there ([Zoho Mail Tracker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoho-mail-tracker-by-craz/ofaolcedokpcmeacofhfnlhgebgjolkc)) which as the name suggests is an email tracker for the Zoho mail client.

It relies on the [GCM notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) for giving information to the user. My question is what should I use as **GCM won't work on Firefox**.

I tried reading a lot and seems like most of the stuff is either obsolete or deprecated. Should I resort to long polling(seems really a bad idea), or websockets?

Or should I simply wait until its properly implemented in Firefox?

Comment: Not a full answer, but `chrome.gcm` API is marked as "unlikely" in the [WebExtensions compatibility roadmap](https://arewewebextensionsyet.com/#gcm). So waiting won't take you far.

Comment: Any suggestions on how should I go ahead then?

Comment: Relevant, close to a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125710/gcm-equivalent-for-firefox/35133879
It seems that currently there's no support for Mozilla-provided push services; you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1364639 states chrome.gcm won't be implemented.