# Is it possible to receive webhook events in web extensions?

Tags: webhooks, firefox-addon-webextensions

We need to get webhook events from a domain in the web extensions itself. That domain is not under our control.

We get the web extension's URL using `browser.identity.getRedirectURL()`. We have registered this as the webhook POST callback URL in other domain.

Is it possible to receive the webhook events whenever the other domain POSTs the data in callback URL? Would it be sufficient to intercept HTTP headers in order to get the data or would we need to have Node modules/servers inside the web extension?

Answer (score 2):

No, not like you described. This is a pretty deep misunderstanding how webhooks and/or `browser.identity` work.

Your webextension is running on a client machine; it's not a webserver listening for connections (an extension can't do that at all).

So whenever some *other* machine that emits a webhook event tries to connect to the endpoint provided, whatever it connects to is *not* your extension.

You make an allusion to `browser.identity.getRedirectURL()` and seem to think that this is a real address that is assigned to your webextension and others can `POST` to it (and your extension be somehow informed about it).

This is not the case: instead, it's a "virtual" URL that the browser will treat specially if you (the browser) navigates to it. That request never actually leaves your machine to some server. No other client can connect to it (except for other browsers with the same extension - but again it will only ever reach them).

A solution for receiving webhooks would be to have an actual webserver somewhere that can receive them, plus some sort of push mechanism to inform your extension of the event:

- A persistent WebSocket connection to your "receiver" server.
- <del>[GCM push messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm) initiated by your "receiver" server.</del> [Not for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125710/gcm-equivalent-for-firefox/35133879)

Comment: Maybe you can help me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843135/why-is-the-identity-launchwebauthflow-not-returning-to-my-extension?